# shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape how to solve this type of error in python?

Tags: python

how to solve this type of error in python??

"ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape" and my code is:

Code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    cancer.data, cancer.target, random_state=0)
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)
forest.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("Accuracy on training set: {:.3f}".format(forest.score(X_train, y_train)))
print("Accuracy on test set: {:.3f}".format(forest.score(X_test, y_test)))
plot_feature_importances_cancer(forest)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're getting the error.
I was able to run it with your code, but try copying the following.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_feature_importances_cancer(model):
    n_features = cancer.data.shape[1]
    plt.barh(range(n_features), model.feature_importances_, align='center')
    plt.yticks(np.arange(n_features),  cancer.feature_names)
    plt.xlabel("Feature importtances")
    plt.ylabel("Feature")

cancer = load_breast_cancer()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    cancer.data, cancer.target, random_state=0)
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)
forest.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("Accuracy on training set: {:.3f}".format(forest.score(X_train, y_train)))
print("Accuracy on test set: {:.3f}".format(forest.score(X_test, y_test)))

plot_feature_importances_cancer(forest)
```

Comment: Thank you. This error occurs when running to code ：plot_feature_importances_cancer(forest)，Do you know why

Comment: Perhaps the length of the x and y axes were uneven while running matplotlib. You can run `print` and `shape` in the function code and check it as you go: D